Как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялась переменная C#
Делаю свою первую игру кликер на юнити, нужна помощь с тем, чтобы "увидеть" нажатие на кнопку и изменить значение переменной money
Вот код:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TFM : MonoBehaviour
{
    //ниже мои попытки сделать так чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялась переменная
    public Text t_wght;
    public Button button1;

    public void Butpr()
    {
        if (OnButtonClick)
        {

        }
    }
    //на этом попытки закончились, дальше код переменной
    public void Text()
    {
        int money;
        money = 0;
        string myString = money.ToString();
        t_wght.text = myString;
    }

}


Во-первых, откуда у вас взялась переменная OnButtonClick? Во-вторых, найдите в сети как сделать кликер в unity, гайдов - куча, времени сэкономите и себе и жителям форума.

Я, человек совершенно не разбирающийся ни в c#, ни в Unity загуглил это 1 кликом. Прописываете myButton.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClick);, где myButton - название вашей кнопки, а OnButtonClick - указатель на функцию при нажатии.

В Unity есть замечательный компонент TextMeshProUGUI , если сделать :
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _textMeshProUGUI;

А затем в нужном методе сделать:
public void SomeMethod()
{
    _textMeshProUGUI.fontSize += value; //float значение
}

То при изменении значения value можно добиться изменения размера текста.
Убедитесь , что у вас используется пространство имён using TMPro;.
